# How many funding ($M) do you get for 1 unit of rare metal exported to Earth?

Tags: surviving-mars

How many funding ($M) do you get for 1 Rare Metal sold to Earth?

From Encyclopedia (in-game) :

> [...] Rare metals are mostly used for manufacturing electronics and for exporting back to Earth

Does it vary depending of the mission or the acquired technologies ?

Comment: It looks like it is based off of the sponsor you choose...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's based off the sponsor you choose. Most sponsors pay $25M per unit, with some paying slightly less.

Blue Sun are notable here as they pay $30M- significantly more than other companies.